# Ruby on rails arithmetic expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller action like this:

```
def index    
    @start_limit = 0    
    @last_limit = 5    
    @start = params[:start]    
    @last = params[:next]    
    if @last    
      @start_limit = (@Start_limit) + (@last)  
      @last_limit = (@last_limit) + (@last)  
    elsif @start  
      @start_limit = (@start_limit) - (@start)  
      @last_limit = (@last_limit) - (@start)  
    else  
      # do nothing  
    end  
end
```

While I am executing program containing such controller action then following error occurs:
`undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`. I need a solution.
I'm new in RoR, I welcome anyone's suggestion.

Comment: You should make good questions if you want good answers: 1) Highlight your code blocks. 2) Use 2-spaces indentation. 3) Try to better explain us your problem, provide the whole error and the line it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if @last    
      @start_limit = (@Start_limit) + (@last)  
      @last_limit = (@last_limit) + (@last)  
    elsif @start  
      @start_limit = (@start_limit) - (@start)  
      @last_limit = (@last_limit) - (@start)  
    else
```

to

```
if @last    
      @start_limit = (@start_limit) + (@last)  
      @last_limit = (@last_limit) + (@last)  
    elsif @start  
      @start_limit = (@start_limit) - (@start)  
      @last_limit = (@last_limit) - (@start)  
    else
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is a case sensitive language so `@start_limit` and `@Start_limit` (7th line, capital s) are two different variables. Change this to lowercase and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

`@start_limit = (@Start_limit) + (@last)`

with:

`@start_limit = (@start_limit) + (@last)`